# how do i disable frame rate limit in chrome version 84 and higher?

Tags: google-chrome, version

Since version 84 in chrome and up, the devtools fps meter has changed and also the ability to use

```
--disable-frame-rate-limit
```

argument when launching chrome does not uncap fps. Does anyone know how to disable the frame rate limit? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
--disable-frame-rate-limit  --disable-gpu-vsync --max-gum-fps="9999"
```

this combination of start arguments seems to unlock the frame cap

Comment: is this not accessible in `chrome://flags` anymore?

Comment: is there any other way to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

i tried this though, FPS 59.4 limited out of nowhere (i don't know where it limited)
and cause troubles to stability of chrome and all chrome apps don't work especially in aero.

chrome Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32029572)